# Are there populations with comprehensive genealogies for most members?

Tags: census-records, iceland

Are there any human populations for which comprehensive genealogies (or just pedigrees) have been compiled? eg researchers compile genealogy data in their study of a island population.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[Iceland’s Entire Family Tree is Online](https://blog.eogn.com/2017/02/28/icelands-entire-family-tree-is-online/):

> One country has everyone’s family tree, complete with original source
>   citations, online and available for all the country’s citizens to see.
>   In fact, there is even an Android app available to show each Icelandic
>   citizen his or her genealogy, in most cases back to 874 AD.

Comment: Does this account for immigration?

Comment: I don't know.  You could ask the blog's author.